# Pass Date Picker date back to View Controller to show Date in label

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uilabel, nsdate

*I've researched a bunch of questions on how to do this, and am coming up just short.*

I have ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB.

`ViewControllerB` is passing the `NSDate` from the `UIDatePicker` back to `ViewControllerA`.

I'm fine until **trying to put that `NSDate` as a label in the `TableViewCell` it corresponds with.**

Can you help?  Thanks!

ViewControllerA

```
- (void)addItemViewController:(EXEDurationPickerViewController *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSString *)item {
    NSLog(@"This was returned from ViewControllerB %@", item);
}
```

**`item` is the Date picked from ViewControllerB.  How do I get it to show up as a label in the corresponding TableViewCell?**

Comment: What do you mean by "corresponding TableViewCell"? Is it the one you clicked on that sent you to ViewControllerB in the first place?

Comment: Yes.  Sorry for not being clearer on that

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1

Comment: @duci9y not really, more specific than that, but thanks for the hard work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `delegate` to pass the date or other option is send `Notificaition`

Add this in `ViewControllerA`

```
@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController{
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
}
@end

-(void)viewDidLoad{

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) 
        name:@"dateSend"
        object:nil];
}

- (void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
   NSString *item =  notification.userInfo[@"date"];

   // show for what cell you want to show
    //keep selectedIndexPath as instance Variable
    YourCell *cell = (YourCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];
    cell.label.text = item;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
//Post the notification fro `ViewControllerB`
- (void)addItemViewController:(EXEDurationPickerViewController *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSString *)item {
    NSLog(@"This was returned from ViewControllerB %@", item);


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"TestNotification" object:nil userInfo:@{@"date":item}];
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help!  The only part I'm not totally tracking on is `cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];` what I would use as `selectedIndexPath`.  Can you help me understand that a bit better?

Comment: on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` save the indexPath to some intstance variable say `NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath` and on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` assign it to `selectedIndesPath`

Answer (score 1):

In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath (or in prepareForSegue if you're using that instead) save the indexPath of the selected cell in a property. Then, in your delegate method, add item to your model (whatever you're populating your table view with), and then call reloadRowsAtIndexPath: with that saved indexPath to update the table.